# Formatting repeated date data in time dependent survival format

Tags: r, survival-analysis, survival

referencing the following manual for time dependent survival in R:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf

From the vignette example:

```
subject time1 time2 death creatinine
 5       0     90    0     0.9
 5       90    120   0     1.5
 5       120   185   1     1.2
```

The data I have is in the following format:

In dd-mm-yyyy format

```
subject date           death creatinine
 5       01-01-2022     0     0.9
 5       01-04-2022     0     1.5
 5       01-05-2022     0     1.2
 5        05-07-2022     1     1.2
```

I need to format the data below to match to the data above.

Answer (score 1):

You can't fill in `time2` in the last row without more information. In single-event data, if an individual has the event (like in your example), `time2` value in the final row would typically be the time of the event (in the final row). For those that don't have the event, `time2` might be the time the observation for that individual ended.

So, excluding the final `time2` value per `subject`, you can do something like this

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  # change date to Date using as.Date()
  mutate(date=as.Date(date,"%d-%m-%y")) %>% 
  # arrange the rows by date
  arrange(date) %>% 
  # group by subject
  group_by(subject) %>% 
  # for each subject, create time2 and time1
  mutate(
    time2 = as.numeric(lead(date)-min(date)-1),
    time1 = lag(time2), 
    time1 = if_else(row_number()==1, 0, time1)
  ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  # move time1 next to time2
  relocate(time1,.before = time2)
```

Output:

```
  subject date       death creatinine time1 time2
    <int> <date>     <int>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1       5 2020-01-01     0        0.9     0    90
2       5 2020-04-01     0        1.5    90   120
3       5 2020-05-01     1        1.2   120    NA
```